# Detect hidden/invisible watermark in videos

Tags: video

Lately, I have been interested in Watermark & steganography.

And as a part of research i am working on, i have a mp4 video file that has a hidden/invisible Watermark.

My question is is there an easy/simple way/tool (that you experienced) to detect the hidden/invisible Watermark in videos ?